# Spectrum of bounded holomorphic functions on the unit disk

Tags: complex-analysis, algebraic-geometry, smooth-manifolds, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I'm working on an exercise (8.31) in the book *Smooth Manifolds and Observables* by Jet Nestruev. Let me reformulate the exercise as follows:

Let $\mathcal F$ be the algebra of bounded holomorphic functions on the unit open disk $B(0,1)$. Show that the maximal ideals of $\mathcal F$ are exactly one of the following two types:

1. $\mathfrak{m}_x$, where $|x|<1$. This is the ideal of functions in $\mathcal F$ vanishing at $x$.
2. $\mathfrak{m}_x$, where $|x|=1$. This is the ideal of functions in $\mathcal F$ whose limit as $z\to x$ exists and equals $0$.

First I'm having trouble showing that $\mathfrak{m}_x$ is a maximal ideal when $|x|=1$. This amounts to proving that if $f$ is bounded and holomorphic on $B(0,1)$ with $\lim_{z\to x}f(z)$ unequal to $0$ (possibly does not exist), then there is $g\in\mathcal F$ such that the limit of $fg$ at $z=x$ is $1$.

I also don't know how to prove that these are *all* possible maximal ideals in $\mathcal F$. Any help (hint) would be appreciated.

Comment: A heuristic to show that they are the only maximal ideals: if $I$ is an ideal and $f\in I$ is such that 1) $f$ has no zero in the unit disk, and 2) $f$ does not go to zero at any point of the boundary, then show that $1/f$ is holomorphic and bounded on the disk. It would follow that $1/f \times f = 1 \in I$ and that $I$ is the whole set of holomorphic functions.

Comment: this is a bit misleading since for every $|x|=1$ there are uncountably many maximal ideals $M_{x,j}$ which consist of function in $\mathcal F$ that vanish in the limit on some subsequence going to $x$ - in other words each $|x|=1$ gives rise to uncountably many maximal ideals of the algebra, not to a single one - your example in point $2$ is not a maximal ideal since for example for $x=1$ it is strictly contained in the ideal obtained by adding the function $f(z)=e^{\frac{z+1}{z-1}}$ to it which satisfies $f(r) \to 0, r \to 1^-$ but $f(z)$ has other limit points when $z \to 1$

Comment: another way to see the complexity of the space of maximal ideals of $\mathcal F$ is to note that any maximal ideal $M_L$ of $L^{\infty}$ gives rise to a (unique - this is not hard to prove) maximal ideal $M=M_L \cap \mathcal F$ of $\mathcal F$ and it is easily seen that the maximal ideal space of $L^{\infty}$ while also huge is totally disconnected in the natural Gelfand topology, while it is also not that hard to show that the maximal ideal space of $\mathcal F$ is actually connected in the Gelfand topology, so is even huger so to speak

Comment: @Conrad I'm pretty sure that what I wrote is exactly what the exercise wants us to prove, so I guess the exercise is wrong, then.

Comment: could be - the result holds for the algebra of holomorphic functions in the unit disc that extend continuously to the boundary but the maximal spectrum of the algebra of bounded holomorphic functions on the unit disc is huge; there are some famous theorems like the Corona theorem (the open disc regarded as a subset of the spectrum is dense in the Gelfand or weak-* topology) that are extremely difficult and describe some of the features of this spectrum; also the Silov boundary results are fairly involved though more straightforward